# Understanding why my Rails 4 App is randomly timing out

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

For the past few months, my site (running on Rails 4 with Heroku) has been having no issues. Traffic has been steady and response times below 500 ms.

Randomly today, response times shot up to 20,000 ms+.

[image: Heroku response times]

When looking at my logs, I noticed ActiveRecord taking unusually long to run a `SELECT DISTINCT COUNT`. This, in fact, seemed to be causing the slow loads.

```
(5029.1ms)  SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT "impressions"."session_hash") FROM "impressions" WHERE "impressions"."impressionable_id" = $1 AND "impressions"."impressionable_type" = $2  [["impressionable_id", 826], ["impressionable_type", "Article"]]
```

I want to say this is being caused by the impressionist gem and my counter cache that I am using to display article count, but I am not sure.

I am now also seeing this error in my logs for the first time:

```
PG::DuplicatePstatement: ERROR:  prepared statement "a9" already exists
```

Any help understanding what is going on would be awesome. Can't seem to find documentation on the issue. Very strange that my app has solidly been running for months now, and just today it decides to go downhill.

I am also using the Rack Timeout gem with Heroku. I heard this gem can directly or indirectly cause the above error, but I just can wrap my head around why any of this is happening. Let me know if there is any other info or metrics I can provide.

**One-Day-Later Update:**

Response times went back to normal on their own (< 500 ms). Can't figure out why such a random spike.

And just for reference, the above `SELECT DISTINCT COUNT` query was being executed from this code in my article show page which is simply counting the impressions unique to the session:

```
<%= @article.impressionist_count(filter: :session_hash) %>
```

Comment: Are you using the paid version of Heroku or free?

Comment: Paid... running on a Standard 2X Dyno and Hobby Basic DB (with 10m rows) @CheeseFry

Comment: Can you post the Ruby code that generates that query?

Answer (score 0):

This error `PG::DuplicatePstatement: ERROR:  prepared statement "a9" already exists` happened because you have prepared statements enabled. I don't know what is the exact cause of this error. I saw it randomly during my test builds and in some other places. I would generally recommend you to disable prepared statements, because it can save you some real trouble. When you get more traffic and try to scale up your dynos you can start seeing out of memory errors from pg gem.

To disable just add this to your database.yml

```
production:
    adapter: postgresql
    prepared_statements: false
```

You can also disable it for other environments.

Coming back to initial problem, generally `COUNT` queries are slow in Postgres especially with `DISTINCT` so you should probably try to optimize it. But since it is random spike, I would bet that it was caused by `AUTOVACUUM`. If you are not familiar, `AUTOVACUUM` is like a garbage collector that removes deleted rows from disk, collects statistics etc. When running it creates a lot of IO traffic which slows other queries. By default it is invoked after 20% of rows in the table change and you cannot predict exactly when it will happen. It is possible to run it manually during night hours or just during low traffic. Just type `VACUUM ANALYZE table_name;` in psql.

You can also see the database stats related to autovacuum (last time it was executed, how many rows changed etc). The easiest way is to install `https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras` and run `heroku pg:vacuum-stats`